# Implementing CRC32 module with verilog for FPGA

Tags: switch-statement, verilog, fpga, ethernet, crc32

I'm sort of new to FPGA. I'm having a project  on this field this summer which is implementing Ethernet switch with 4ports. I've coded all the parts to check preamble and MAC address and etc and they're working correctly
but I have serious problem with implementing CRC32.

- I know the algorithm of CRC32 from IEEE 802.3
- then, created a frame with 18 Bytes of data
- then generated the CRC of my frame with this applet ( here's [a link](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html)!

but with any frame I make, the result of checking CRC for that particular frame is wrong ( means with my module, every frame has error )

I'd be more than happy to know your opinion

Here is my code of CRC32 module :

```
module CRC( clk10x, clk, rst, SFD, length, lengthReady, dataIn, hasError//, MACready
);
   .
   .
// input and outputs and registers are here
   .
   .
   . 
initial
begin
    CRC <= 32'h04C11DB7;
    zeros <= 32'h00000000;
end

always @ ( posedge clk10x )
begin
    if ( rst )
    begin
        counter32bit <= 0;
        shiftFlag <= 1;
        shift <= 0;
        shift2 <= 0;
        first32bit <= 0;
        state <= 0;
        index <= 0;
        calcEnd <= 0;
    end

    else if ( clk )
    begin
        if ( SFD )
        begin

            case ( state )
                'b00 : begin
                            first32bit <= ( counter32bit == 32 ) ? 1 : 0;
                            state <= ( first32bit ) ? 'b01 : 'b00;
                            {MSB, window} <= {window, ~dataIn};     // shift Register;
                            counter32bit <= counter32bit + 1;
                        end
                'b01 : begin
                            {MSB, window} <= ( MSB ) ? ( {window, dataIn} ^ CRC ) : {window, dataIn};
                            shift <= ( lengthReady && shiftFlag ) ? ( length * 8 ) : shift - 1;
                            shiftFlag <= ( lengthReady ) ? 0 : shiftFlag;
                            shift2 <= ( shift == 0 && lengthReady ) ? 32 : shift2 -1;
                            //shift2 <= ( !shift2 ) ? shift2 - 1 : shift2;
                            state <= ( shift2 == 2 && lengthReady ) ? 'b10 : 'b01;
                         end
                'b10 : begin
                            {MSB, window} <= ( MSB && !calcEnd ) ? ( {window, zeros[index]} ^ CRC ) : {window, zeros[index]};
                            index <= ( index == 32 && !calcEnd ) ? 40 : index + 1;
                            calcEnd <= ( index == 40 ) ? 1 : 0;
                            state <= ( calcEnd ) ? 'b11 : state;

                         end

                'b11 : begin
                            window <= window ^ 32'b11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111;
                            hasError <= ( window == 0 ) ? 0 : 1;
                         end
                default : begin
                                //state <= 0;
                                first32bit <= 0;
                                //shift <= 0;
                             end
            endcase

            // have to assign index 0 again
        end
```

Comment: How does window get initialized?  The register being shifted needs to start with all ones.

Comment: Why is that ?
could you please guide me through checking the frame with CRC32 algorithm ?

Comment: It's right there on the web site you linked.  Initial value FFFFFFFF.  It looks like you are implementing the final xor value, FFFFFFFF.

Answer (score 4):

CRC calculations are realized on a per bit basis. so every input data word - lets say one byte per clock cycle @ 125 MHz for gigabit Ethernet - results in 8 CRC calculations per clock cycle. So your code needs an extra loop to do this 8 sub-cycle calculations.

I would also advice to split up your fsm into a control state machine and crc calculation (data path).

As Mark Adler noticed, the initial value of the CRC's internal LFSR must be initialized with 0xFFFFFFFF. I can see this in your code.

Why do you use 2 different clocks in your process?

### Edit 1:

I'm not so good in coding verilog, so I'll copy some VHDL code from our VHDL library. I think you will be able to translate the statements into corresponding verilog code.
I spared the separate register process with reset and clock enable :)

```
-- Compute next combinational Value
process(lfsr, din)
  variable v : std_logic_vector(lfsr'range);
begin
  v := lfsr;
  for i in BITS-1 downto 0 loop
    v := (v(v'left-1 downto 0) & '0') xor
         (GN and (GN'range => (din(i) xor v(v'left))));
  end loop;
  lfsn <= v;
end process;
```

- BITS is a generic and set to 32
- lfsr (linear feedback shift register) is 32 bit wide and stores the current "checksum"
- the temp. variable v is initialized by the current register value (lfsr)
- the for loop goes over every bit of din (data in) and performs the crc calculation (shift + xor)
- => so 32 CRC calculations are performed per clock cycle
- GN is the normalized generator polynomial of CRC32
- the result is stored in lfsn (next lfsr value) which is connected to a 32 bit wide D-FF with reset and clock enable

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

I used two clocks because of Manchester decode module. my board clk will be clk10x and clk works as an enable flag and other modules work with this clk.

My main request is to guide me through implementing CRC32 for Ethernet pleaaaaaaaaaase.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2295408 I added the core computation loop for CRC in VHDL, because I'm not so good in Verilog.

Comment: Sorry for answering late.
Thanks , it did helped me.

Now I have completed my code. is there any program or reliable applet which I can use to generate an Ethernet frame ?
I've already used some CRC32 generators applet on the net. but they can't be 100% accurate since they are self-made.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: For example for a data like :
0010A47BEA800012345678900012000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1011
in hex, what would be the CRC32 ?

Comment: So if my answer was good enough you can vote it up ;) So you are looking for test data ... I used wireshark to capture some frames and copied them into a VHDL testbench. Just create a vector of a 8-bit vector to store multiple bytes. Now you can use a process which reads from that vector one byte per cycle to drive your modules input.

Comment: I can't vote it up, because I've recently signed up here & still dont have enough reputation ( at least 15 reputation needed to vote ).
will do when got enough credit ;)
Thanks, I'll give it a try with Wireshark.